# What does "read chapter 18 onwards" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, terminology

What does "read chapter 18 onwards" mean? Read until chapter 18 or from 18 to end of the book? This is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This means *read chapter 18 and keep going*, as in chapter 18 and all those that come after it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This means to read all of Chapter 18 and continue reading until the end of the book.

This typically refers to reading the chapters and not the back matter, which are sections that follow the main text, such as the index, glossary, notes and appendices.

There is no need to read anything before Chapter 18.